# Adding a range of numbers python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, range, addition

I am trying to print the even integers and then add and print the odd integers in this range of numbers. I have been stuck for a while and cant seem to figure out what I need to do.

```
first = int(raw_input("Input the lower integer : "))
second = int(raw_input("Input the higher integer : "))

def calc(even,odd):
    for even in range(first, second+1):
        if(even % 2 == 0):
            print even
    for odd in range(first, second+1):
        if(odd % 2 > 0):
            print odd


calc(first,second)
```

Comment: You're not adding them. Create a counter, `odd_total = 0` then add to it each time you get an odd number.

Comment: Should you be changing your parameters to `calc()` to be called `first` and `second`, not `odd` and `even`? Your current scope and namings are pretty confusing

Comment: Add the odd numbers to what?

Comment: @jxpython I want the sum of all of the odd numbers in a given range.

Comment: @ZachCook but you still want the function to print the even numbers? Or just the sum of the odd numbers in the range?

Comment: @jxpython print both, the even numbers and then the sum of the odd numbers

Comment: @ZachCook see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This prints all even numbers then the sum of the odd numbers:

```
first = int(raw_input("Input the lower integer : "))
second = int(raw_input("Input the higher integer : "))

def calc(first, second):
    sumOdds = 0
    for i in range(first, second+1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print 'Even: ', i
        else:
            sumOdds += i

    print(sumOdds)


calc(first,second)
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question perfectly. Appreciate your help my friend.

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I was unaware what the checkmark did. I changed it to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
first = int(input("Input the lower integer : "))
second = int(input("Input the higher integer : "))


def calc(first, second):

    for even in range(first, second + 1):
        if not even % 2:
            print('Even: ', even)

    for odd in range(first, second + 1):
        if odd % 2:
            print('Odd: ', odd)

    return sum(range(first, second + 1))

print('Sum: ', calc(first, second))
```

Sorry, I used python3...

Answer (score 0):

You're off to a good start, but keep in mind that variable names like `odd` and `even` are just names that you assign and does not mean that value will be odd or even.

In fact, in the two loops that you made

```
for even in range(first, second+1)
for odd in range(first, second+1)
```

`odd` and `even` will both iterate over the same numbers. So there is no need to loop twice, you can just loop once, since a number will always either be even or odd, so you can combine the two loops like this

```
for num in range(first, second+1):
    if(num % 2 == 0):
        print 'even', num
    else:
        print 'odd', num
```

Now instead of printing you can do whatever you want, i.e adding the odd numbers